# Starting Assembly x86 - MASM

Tags: winapi, assembly, architecture, x86, masm

Alright, my knowledge of C/C++ & the winAPI is fairly intermediate and I'm not new to assembly.

However I would like to get more in depth of actually programming in assembly and learning about certain features at a lower level and understand how they work:

Things I'm interested in:
The stack, how PE is mapped into memory, interrupts, kernels & drivers etc.

I want to really get a strong understanding of the architecture that surrounds Windows.

Where would you suggest me to start? I would be glad if you could provide either a book title or a link for me to follow.

Much appreciated!

Comment: I would guess almost none of the topics you mention you're interested in are implemented significantly in assembly.  Or is this a two-parter?

Comment: book http://www.amazon.com/Windows-Internals-Part-Covering-Server/dp/0735648735/ref=pd_sim_b_3

Comment: For the PE stuff, check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx & http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ms809762.aspx & http://www.hbgary.com/loading-a-dll-without-calling-loadlibrary

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to the intel architecutre software manuals:

http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html

It's a fairly good place to start, to learn the opcodes and registries, the flow